# MySQL Attendance Calculation

Tags: mysql, sql

Here i have table attendances

[image]

I need result as shown below

[image]

How can i achieve this in mysql without using any programming language

Sql File is [Attendances.sql](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MIxs1LgKLzhHaaK0QHGaF58niqSveOnp)

Comment: Can there be multiple IN/OUT values per day?

Comment: In the expected result, for the `user_id 5` the `date` value should be `2019-04-22` right?

Comment: Is there a reason you unaccepted my answer?

Comment: I answer this que please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Achieve it my self by creating a mysql function and view

Mysql View

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `view_attendances` AS
    SELECT 
        `a`.`id` AS `a1_id`,
        `a`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,
        CAST(`a`.`date_time` AS DATE) AS `date`,
        `a`.`date_time` AS `in`,
        `a2`.`id` AS `a2_id`,
        `a2`.`date_time` AS `out`,
        (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
            `a`.`date_time`,
            `a2`.`date_time`) / 3600) AS `hours`
    FROM
        (`attendances` `a`
        JOIN `attendances` `a2` ON (((`a`.`is_confirm` = 1)
            AND (`a`.`status` = 'IN')
            AND (`a2`.`id` = FN_NEXT_OUT_ATTENDANCE_ID(`a`.`user_id`, `a`.`date_time`, `a`.`status`))
            AND (a2.status = 'OUT')
            AND (CAST(`a`.`date_time` AS DATE) = CAST(`a2`.`date_time` AS DATE)))))
```

Mysql Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION `fn_next_out_attendance_id`( _user_id INT, _attendance_date_time DATETIME, _status VARCHAR(10) ) RETURNS int(11) 
BEGIN
   DECLARE _id INT(11);
SELECT
   id INTO _id 
FROM
   attendances 
WHERE
   is_confirm = 1 
   AND user_id = _user_id 
   AND date_time > _attendance_date_time 
   AND `status` <> _status 
ORDER BY
   date_time ASC LIMIT 1 ;
RETURN if (_id IS NULL, 0, _id);
END
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try a pivot query approach, aggregating by user and date:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    DATE(date_time) AS date,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
                  MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'IN' THEN date_time END),
                  MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'OUT' THEN date_time END)) / 60.0 AS hours
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    user_id,
    DATE(date_time);
```

The caveats of this answer are many.  It assumes that there would be only one `IN` and `OUT` entry, per user, per day.  If a period could cross over dates, then my answer might not generate correct results.  Also, if an `IN` or `OUT` value be missing, then `NULL` would be reported for the `hours` value.

Comment: OP probably wants `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE ...) / 60`

Comment: @Nick You're right, but answer has even bigger problems than this :-(

Comment: But u can use select fields in group so no need to use date function twice, but `group by \`date\``